# IR transmitter Frequency for Universal Remote of TV and AC

Tags: infrared

I have searched thoroughly but still confused which IR transmitter will be best for making a universal remote of TV and AC.

Standard frequency is 38 kHz and others are 36, 38, 40, 42, 48 and 56 kHz.

Can I use 940 nm wavelength IR LED as a transmitter for my application, just for clarification?

Just like "Xiaomi Original Xiaomi Universal IR Remote Controller".

So please, suggest which will be best for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given frequencies of 38kHz, 36kHz, 40kHz etc are carrier frequencies, and has nothing to do with the wavelength of IR LED used. Those frequencies are the rates at which IR LED is switched on and off. They are further modulated by the signal waveforms.
However, while considering the receivers, only a specific receiver works for a specific carrier frequency. For example, use TSOP-1738 for 38kHz carrier frequency. The output of the receiver will be just the signal waveform (carrier gets filtered out)

So as far a universal remote is considered, any IR LED should work.